# RecursionLimit while forming lagrangian in modeling of spherical pendulum

Tags: recursion, wolfram-mathematica

I am new to Mathematica and this gives me headache. I was modeling spherical pendulum using rotationary matrices and it gives me reclim exception at forming lagrangian (L=T-V). Any idea where is the recursion and where is the problem? (I studied documentation but i can see nothing helpful there). File: [Download](http://uloz.to/x2MrpJfL/sphericalpendulummodel-nb)

```
In[55]:= Clear["Global`*"]
p2 = {0, 0, -L}

Out[56]= {0, 0, -L}

In[57]:= R10 = {{Cos[\[Theta][t]], -Sin[\[Theta][t]], 
   0}, {Sin[\[Theta][t]], Cos[\[Theta][t]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

Out[57]= {{Cos[\[Theta][t]], -Sin[\[Theta][t]], 0}, {Sin[\[Theta][t]],
   Cos[\[Theta][t]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}

In[58]:= Grid[R10]

Out[58]= \!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Theta]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Theta]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}]}], "0"},
{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Theta]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}], 
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Theta]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}], "0"},
{"0", "0", "1"}
},
AutoDelete->False,
GridBoxItemSize->{
     "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
      "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
      "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}],
"Grid"]\)

In[59]:= R21 = {{Cos[\[Phi][t]], 0, -Sin[\[Phi][t]]}, {0, 1, 
   0}, {Sin[\[Phi][t]], 0, Cos[\[Phi][t]]}}

Out[59]= {{Cos[\[Phi][t]], 0, -Sin[\[Phi][t]]}, {0, 1, 
  0}, {Sin[\[Phi][t]], 0, Cos[\[Phi][t]]}}

In[60]:= Grid[R21]

Out[60]= \!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Phi]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}], "0", 
RowBox[{"-", 
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Phi]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}]}]},
{"0", "1", "0"},
{
RowBox[{"Sin", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Phi]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}], "0", 
RowBox[{"Cos", "[", 
RowBox[{"\[Phi]", "[", "t", "]"}], "]"}]}
},
AutoDelete->False,
GridBoxItemSize->{
     "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
      "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
      "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}],
"Grid"]\)

In[61]:= p0 = R10 . R21 . p2

Out[61]= {L Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Phi][t]], 
 L Sin[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Phi][t]], -L Cos[\[Phi][t]]}

In[62]:= v0 = D[p0, t]

Out[62]= {-L Sin[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Phi][t]] Derivative[1][\[Theta]][
    t] + L Cos[\[Theta][t]] Cos[\[Phi][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t], 
 L Cos[\[Theta][t]] Sin[\[Phi][t]] Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] + 
  L Cos[\[Phi][t]] Sin[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t], 
 L Sin[\[Phi][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]}

In[63]:= T = 1/2 m v0 . v0 // Simplify

Out[63]= 1/2 L^2 m (Sin[\[Phi][t]]^2 Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]^2 + 
   Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]^2)

In[64]:= V = m {0, 0, g} . p0

Out[64]= -g L m Cos[\[Phi][t]]

In[65]:= L = T - V

During evaluation of In[65]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Out[65]= Hold[g L m Cos[\[Phi][t]]]
```

Comment: `T` and `V` are expressions continiang `L`, so when you assign to `L` you get infinite recursion.  (  just do `x = 2 x` .. same error ).   BTW when you post mathematica code ( ie without the In[]: ..  tags ) you should post only the actual code, do not copy entire cells.

Comment: Oh my god you are right my length l should be lowercase so it doesn't mix with Lagrangian. Thank you :)